# No output using parallel in tandem with ag or ack

Tags: gnu-parallel, ag

I have a list of java reserved words, first letter capitalised.

```
$ tail -n5 ~/reservedjava.txt
Break
While
True
False
Null
```

I'm trying to look through all my java source code to find methods that look like `getWhile()`.

```
cat ~/reservedjava.txt | parallel 'ag "get{}\(\)$"'
```

This shows me nothing. Now, I know that I have a method `getBreak()`:

```
$ ag "getBreak\(\)$"
src/main/java/Foo.java
154:  public Break getBreak()
```

Here's what a dry run looks like:

```
$ cat ~/reservedjava.txt | parallel --dry-run 'ag "get{}\(\)$"' | tail -n5
ag "getBreak\(\)$"
ag "getWhile\(\)$"
ag "getTrue\(\)$"
ag "getFalse\(\)$"
ag "getNull\(\)$"
```

I'm using [gnu parallel](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/parallel/) (v. 20130722) and [the silver searcher (ag)](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) (v. 0.18.1). If it makes a difference, I'm on Fedora 19, but have compiled these utilities myself. I get the same result with ack (v. 2.12).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat ~/reservedjava.txt | parallel 'ag "get{}\(\)$"'
```

This doesn't work because `ag` wants a path argument. Eg, search *where*.

This works, recursively search starting at the current directory:

```
cat ~/reservedjava.txt | parallel 'ag "get{}\(\)$" ./'
```